# Как удалить из таблицы chat записи по id полученные из select запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Я пытаюсь удалить пользователя из приложения, но сперва мне нужно удалить все связанные с ним записи из таблицы chat. (т.е. для удаления пользователя мне нужно удалить все сообщения из задач в которых он участвует -> удалить все задачи в которых он участвует -> удалить его из всех проектов -> и наконец удалить его из таблицы users).

Я делаю следующий запрос:

```
SELECT C.*, PT.user_id, PT.project_id FROM chat C LEFT JOIN projects_tasks PT ON C.task_id=PT.id WHERE PT.user_id=27
```

Он мне показывает те данные, которые я хочу удалить из таблицы chat.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, я хочу удалить записи из chat по полученным id

```
DELETE FROM chat WHERE id IN (SELECT C.*, PT.user_id, PT.project_id FROM chat C LEFT JOIN projects_tasks PT ON C.task_id=PT.id WHERE PT.user_id=27)
```

Но выдается ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как мне решить эту проблему?**

**Моя структура БД:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо удалить по id... "А давай ка возьмём всё с таблицы _ " `SELECT C.*, PT.user_id, PT.project_id FROM` - где логика? Хотите удалить по id - id и надо "выбирать". Даже текст ошибки подсказывает - выражение в скобках должно содержать 1 колонку (ваш ID)

Comment: @InDevX, Спасибо за комментарий. Тогда, как я понял нужно сделать так:
```DELETE FROM chat WHERE id IN (SELECT C.id FROM chat C LEFT JOIN projects_tasks PT ON C.task_id=PT.id WHERE PT.user_id=27)``` 

Но в таком случае выдается ошибка: ```#1093 - You can't specify target table 'chat' for update in FROM clause```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден, спасибо @InDevX и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Нужный мне запрос: `DELETE FROM chat WHERE id IN (SELECT C.id FROM (SELECT * FROM chat) C LEFT JOIN projects_tasks PT ON C.task_id=PT.id WHERE PT.user_id=27)`